# SAPUI5 Smarttable how to use assocation in binding path

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

trying to build following scenario with 2 different smarttables:
[image]

First table is attached to tab Materials, the second smarttable is attached to Orders tab. When the user selects one row and presses the Drill down button, I want to use the association to_Orders to get from the selected row to the underlying Order data and bind the data to the second smarttable.

On my controller function onDrillDown I get the selected row, but the binding part is unclear to me:

```
var gettingInternalTable = this.byId("table1_1").getTable(),
                gettingAllRows = gettingInternalTable.getRows(),
                oSelIndices = gettingInternalTable.getSelectedIndices();

var OrderTab1_2 = this.getView().byId("table1_2");
OrderTab1_2.setModel(oNewModel);
OrderTab1_2.setEntitySet('ZHUM_C_ORDERS');
            OrderTab1_2.setTableBindingPath("/ZHUM_C_MATERIALS('.1~KYM1.2~.3~.4~000000000000002200.5~KYM%20BET%20ECF%2090%201%203.6~110100.7~.8~TO')/to_ZHUM_C_ORDERS");
            OrderTab1_2.rebindTable(true);
```

Do I need to pass the values from the selected row to a filter one by one or is there a smarter way to do that directly with the association and how to bind this to the other table?